# How to clip Arc from image?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am doing winrt application,i have an image which is circle, i need to clip the arc dynamically from the circular image, with different angles, how can i do this?

Comment: Which is it - WPF, Silverlight or WinRT/XAML? These are similar but different platforms and the imaging stacks are different enough to give you a different answer for each platform.

Comment: @FilipSkakun: i need winrt solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinRT/XAML - you would open the image as a WriteableBitmap and process the pixels manually. You could also do it with DirectX if you have more time and want to get the results quicker.

Useful formulas for a circle to start with:

r<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>

x = r * sin(α)
y = r * cos(α)

Comment: is nt there any path clipping exists for winrt applications?

Comment: No, unfortunately [UIElement.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip) is only for RectangleGeometry and OpacityMask is not supported in XAML. You could still do it with DX though.

Comment: i dont know anything about directX,can you suggest any quick start tutorial?

Comment: I would suggest looking into SharpDX - just install the Direct2D component from NuGet. I just wrote some code to render some text to a bitmap that you might find useful [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/585d3ae5a3e3#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition%2fWriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake - you could make an Path/ArcSegment with ImageBrush Fill - similar to the first part of [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999819/521182).