# Path Geometry Clipping Equvalent in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Today I started porting the page turn sample created [here](http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/tinyapps-pageturner7/) for Windows Phone 7 to WinRT (XAML, C#) for helping [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790655/implementing-book-page-sliding-animation-in-winrt) question posted in Stack Overflow. But during porting I got stuck with the clipping portion of page. In the windows phone sample they are using Path Geometry clipping for clipping the page. But in WinRT It seems only rectangle geometry is supporting for clipping option.

**How can I achieve similar functionality like Path geometry clipping in WinRT?**

You can download the sample windows phone code from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=fe8de857c07b25f7&id=FE8DE857C07B25F7!7372&authkey=!ADhcVhoKdCskrzw)

Please find the Source code i Tried [please download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pxc2zz0d3kj0mj/PageFlipApp.zip)

In that Please find the class PageTurn.cs, I commented the code with issues, in:

```
void left_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //_workingOdd.Clip = _oddClipRegion;       
    //_workingEven.Clip = _evenClipRegion;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit late to give a more complete answer, but I got inspired and started working on a reusable control/page transition. The current prototype is working quite nicely with `RenderTransforms` and `Clip` `Transforms` for nice independent animation support.

[image]

I'll work on that reusable control for WinRT XAML Toolkit, but meanwhile you can check this code:

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="FlipControls.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FlipControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        x:Name="ManipulationGrid"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,TranslateInertia"
        ManipulationStarted="ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationStarted"
        ManipulationDelta="ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationDelta"
        ManipulationCompleted="ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationCompleted">
        <Grid
            x:Name="Page1">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry
                    Rect="0,0,80000,80000">
                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform
                                x:Name="Page1ClipTranslateTransform" />
                            <RotateTransform
                                x:Name="Page1ClipRotateTransform" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Grid
                x:Name="Page1ContentGrid">
                <Image
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    Source="http://bigbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/tropical-beach-screensaver.jpg" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            x:Name="Page2"
            Opacity="0">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry
                    Rect="0,0,80000,80000">
                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform
                                x:Name="Page2ClipTranslateTransform" />
                            <RotateTransform
                                x:Name="Page2ClipRotateTransform" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Grid
                x:Name="Page2ContentGrid">
                <Image
                    x:Name="Page2SampleContentImage"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    Source="http://www.photography-match.com/views/images/gallery/Tropical_Lagoon.jpg" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            x:Name="TransitionGridContainer">
            <Grid
                x:Name="TransitionGrid"
                Opacity="0">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform
                        x:Name="TransitionGridContainerTransform" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry
                        Rect="0,0,80000,80000">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform
                                    x:Name="TransitionGridClipTranslateTransform" />
                                <RotateTransform
                                    x:Name="TransitionGridClipRotateTransform" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </Grid.Clip>
                <Image
                    x:Name="TransitionImage"
                    Stretch="None" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace FlipControls
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            PreloadTransitionGridContentAsync();
        }

        private async Task PreloadTransitionGridContentAsync()
        {
            #region Waiting for page 2 content to load
            var bi = Page2SampleContentImage.Source as BitmapImage;

            if (bi.PixelWidth == 0)
            {
                bi.ImageFailed += (s, e) => new MessageDialog("Need a different sample image.").ShowAsync();
                bi.ImageOpened += (s, e) => PreloadTransitionGridContentAsync();
                return;
            }

            if (Page2ContentGrid.ActualWidth == 0)
            {
                SizeChangedEventHandler sizeChangedEventHandler = null;
                sizeChangedEventHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    PreloadTransitionGridContentAsync();
                    Page2ContentGrid.SizeChanged -= sizeChangedEventHandler;
                };

                Page2ContentGrid.SizeChanged += sizeChangedEventHandler;

                return;
            } 
            #endregion

            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync(Page2ContentGrid);
            TransitionImage.Source = rtb;
            await Task.Delay(40000);
        }

        private bool isCancellationRequested;

        private enum FlipDirections
        {
            Left,
            Right
        }

        private FlipDirections flipDirection;
        private Point manipulationStartPosition;
        private double rotationCenterX;
        private double rotationCenterY;

        private void ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TransitionImage.Source == null)
            {
                CancelManipulation(e);
                return;
            }

            manipulationStartPosition = e.Position;

            if (Page1.Opacity == 1)
            {
                flipDirection = FlipDirections.Left;
                Page2ClipTranslateTransform.X = ManipulationGrid.ActualWidth;
                Page2.Opacity = 1;
                TransitionGridClipTranslateTransform.X = -80000;
                TransitionGridContainerTransform.TranslateX = ManipulationGrid.ActualWidth;
                TransitionGrid.Opacity = .975;
            }
            else
            {
                if (manipulationStartPosition.X >= this.ManipulationGrid.ActualWidth / 2)
                {
                    // Can't flip left since there is no page after the current one
                    CancelManipulation(e);
                    return;
                }

                flipDirection = FlipDirections.Right;

                Page1.Opacity = 1;
            }
        }

        private void ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.isCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (flipDirection == FlipDirections.Left)
            {
                var w = this.ManipulationGrid.ActualWidth;
                var h = this.ManipulationGrid.ActualHeight;

                var cx = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(e.Position.X - w, -w));
                var cy = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
                var angle = (Math.Atan2(cx + manipulationStartPosition.Y - w, -cy) * 180 / Math.PI + +90) % 360;

                this.rotationCenterX = w + cx / 2;

                if (cy < 0)
                {
                    this.rotationCenterY = h;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.rotationCenterY = 0;
                }

                Page2ClipTranslateTransform.X = w + cx / 2;
                Page2ClipTranslateTransform.Y = -40000 + h / 2;
                Page2ClipRotateTransform.CenterX = this.rotationCenterX;
                Page2ClipRotateTransform.CenterY = this.rotationCenterY;
                Page2ClipRotateTransform.Angle = angle;

                TransitionGridClipTranslateTransform.X = -80000 - (cx / 2);
                TransitionGridClipTranslateTransform.Y = -40000 + h / 2;
                TransitionGridClipRotateTransform.CenterX = -cx / 2;
                TransitionGridClipRotateTransform.CenterY = this.rotationCenterY;
                TransitionGridClipRotateTransform.Angle = -angle;

                TransitionGridContainerTransform.TranslateX = w + cx;
                TransitionGridContainerTransform.CenterX = -cx / 2;
                TransitionGridContainerTransform.CenterY = this.rotationCenterY;
                TransitionGridContainerTransform.Rotation = 2 * angle;
            }
        }

        private void ManipulationGrid_OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.isCancellationRequested)
            {
                this.isCancellationRequested = false;
                return;
            }

            var w = this.ManipulationGrid.ActualWidth;
            var h = this.ManipulationGrid.ActualHeight;

            var sb = new Storyboard();
            AddAnimation(sb, Page2ClipTranslateTransform, "X", w / 2);
            AddAnimation(sb, Page2ClipRotateTransform, "CenterX", w / 2);
            AddAnimation(sb, Page2ClipRotateTransform, "Angle", 0);

            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridClipTranslateTransform, "X", -80000 + (w / 2));
            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridClipRotateTransform, "CenterX", w / 2);
            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridClipRotateTransform, "Angle", 0);

            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridContainerTransform, "TranslateX", 0);
            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridContainerTransform, "CenterX", w / 2);
            AddAnimation(sb, TransitionGridContainerTransform, "Rotation", 0);
            sb.Begin();
        }

        private static void AddAnimation(Storyboard sb, DependencyObject dob, string path, double to)
        {
            var da = new DoubleAnimation();
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, dob);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, path);
            da.To = to;
            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2);
            sb.Children.Add(da);
        }

        private void CancelManipulation(ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.isCancellationRequested = true;
            e.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the logic but the effect is not smooth... And the user experience is pretty bad. The image jerks on flipping. Can u suggest the fix to avoid jerking feeling?

Comment: I'm working on a reusable control still. It will have this fixed.

Comment: Hi Filip, Do you completed implementing this reusable control?

Comment: Nah, not yet, had some busy days and then started working on making my toolkit work for the phone, but I'll make it work eventually.

Comment: @FilipSkakun : Any update on the flip control? When we can expect a fully functional control in Winrt Toolkit

Comment: As soon as I get some time to work on it. Sorry I can't give you a better answer. It might happen this week or it might happen in a month.

Comment: Hi Filip : U got chance to integrate this to WinRT XAML toolkit? We are waiting for the feature.. Please update

Answer (score 12):

Hope this helps to you.

Here is the XAML to get exactly the look of the demo you linked to:

***Path Calcualtion***
[image]

**Image1**

```
 <Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid Height="145" Width="210" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Margin="-3" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Border>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Images/1.jpg"></Image>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images/2.jpg" ></Image>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="Images/8.jpg" >
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,49,150"></RectangleGeometry>
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Data="M 180,0 L 153,145 L 85 120 L 160,-12"   >
            <Path.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/4.jpg"/>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        <!--polyline used for path image border-->
        <Polyline Points="180,0,160,-11,85,120,153,145" Margin="0,-2,0,0"  Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Image2**

```
    <Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid Width="290" Height="180" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0"  BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" BorderBrush="White">
            <Image Stretch="Fill"  Source="Images/4.jpg"></Image>
        </Border>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images/3.jpg" ></Image>
        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Data="M 200,0 L 170,180 L 82.5 160 L 130 0 "   >
            <Path.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/6.jpg"/>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        <!--polyline used for path image border-->
        <Polyline Points="130,0,82.5,160,170,180"   Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**OutPut**

[image]

You can enlarge the size of image by putting image1 and image2 grid in viewbox like below

```
 <Viewbox Width="500" Height="350">
    <Grid Width="290" Height="180"/>        
 </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Hi heena, Can you please share the sample project you created. Then it will help us play with the real working source other than this xaml provided.

Comment: Heena. Please update the code provided by Stephan and share it. I think it will help many of them. Till now there is no open source solution to Magazine page flip animation. Any way appreciate you effort. Keep Going Good luck.

Comment: Hi Stephan I recommend to mark this as answered. even though I appreciate Gerri's effort still the answer provided by him is not completely address the question you made.

Comment: Hi heena? I am making this as answered as WinPhone Artist suggested. As everyone suggested, Can you please make a working page flip app for us?

Comment: Hi Stephan i will post flip animation in 2-3 days.

Comment: Thanks Heena... Thank You very much.. I was badly search for a solution to this...

Comment: @Heena : Do u succeed implementing page flip animation? We are waiting for a complete solution.

Comment: Hey Heena.. You tried the page flip implementation ?

Answer (score 7):

So, let's be clear of the status of things.

1. WinRT XAML is now supported on WP 8.1
2. WP Silverlight XAML can do more than WinRT XAML
3. For example, WP SL XAML can use custom paths for clipping
4. WinRT XAML can only use rectangles for clipping
5. Reason: Rectangles out-perform any custom shape, period
6. The XAML team lets performance trump capability
7. Today, the XAML team has no plans to change clipping

Now we understand the problem.
Do we have other options?

If you want to clip an image, you are in luck. You can create a path element of any shape and paint the background with an image brush. This is not technically clipping, but you have the same effect.

```
<Path Data="M540,394 C544.208,422.053 538.553,441.447 514,466 C490.615,489.385 
485.625,493.625 448,456 C423.947,431.947 425.435,394.188 486,374 C457.465,374 
452,353.019 452,312 C452,280.568 446.005,289.33 478,268 C514.938,243.374 
496.654,264 536,264 C538.338,275.69 546,280.948 546,294 C540.421,280.052 
545.708,255.719 564,242 C577.778,231.667 594.285,223.858 610,216 C617.244,212.378 
619.853,219.804 626,228 C630.353,233.805 671.625,322.65 620,302 C660.196,302 
680,306.666 680,374 C680,393.824 652.592,424.592 614,386 C614,403.28 
621.284,411.789 614,430 C607.693,445.768 601.833,454 580,454 C550.466,454 
548.934,443.082 534,414" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="269.872" 
Margin="433.483,215.058,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="247.517">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="Assets/SplashScreen.png"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

That would render this:

[image]

But wait there's more. The ImageBrush itself can be transformed. Meaning you can perform a Translate on the image moving the image around within the path. Moreover you can also apply a rotate on the image.

First, consider an animation like the one FlipBoard does. That gives you a simple page flip animation that looks freaking awesome without actually requiring a complex clipping. Check out this demo: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/12/walkthough-use-xamls-3d-planeprojection.html

Then again, you might simply just want to replicate that Demo. That's fine. The XAML below will give you exactly the effect you want. And it is easy to animate:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="800" Height="400">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/car.jpg"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Grid Width="800" Height="400">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,-400,800,800" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Grid Width="800" Height="400" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" Rotation="30.957" TranslateX="527" TranslateY="108"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/car.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Rectangle Fill="Purple" Opacity=".5" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It would look like this:

Here's the XAML to get exactly the look of the demo you linked to:

```
<Grid Width="800" Height="200" Margin="283,283,283,285">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="-200,-200,1000,400" />
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Path x:Name="Page2" Grid.Column="1" Data="M0.5,0.5 L495,-1 L399.5,199.5 L0.5,199.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,-1.5,-95.5,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-200"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
        <Path.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/Car2.jpg"/>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="Page4" Data="M94,2 L495,-1 L495,201 L0.5,199.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Margin="400,-3.5,-495.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Path.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/Car4.jpg"/>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="200"/>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Image x:Name="Page1" Source="Assets/Car1.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Grid x:Name="Page3" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-156" Rotation="25" TranslateY="-94" ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,200" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Border BorderThickness="5,5,5,0" BorderBrush="White">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="175"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Image x:Name="Page3Image" Source="Assets/Car3.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Would look like this:

[image]

I am not sure how much tweaking this would take to get right, Stephan. My guess is... plenty. The good news is: you can animate transforms on the GPU so most of this should be accelerated. :)

// Jerry

Answer (score 2):

For images - you can simply use an `ImageBrush` and use it to fill a `Path` that has the desired geometry. For anything more complicated - use `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()` to turn your XAML into a bitmap and go back to answer 1.

Comment: Hi Filip, I am using Canvas instead of Image, Can you please take a look into the source code i added here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pxc2zz0d3kj0mj/PageFlipApp.zip). And please suggest the changes if you have time. Please help me

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to dig deep into your code, but you should consider `RenderTargetBitmap` if you are targeting Windows 8.1, so you could simplify it. Another option that seems like a better solution for what you are trying to achieve might be to use a `RectangleGeometry` `Clip` with a `Transform` - that way you could achieve the same result without using arbitrary geometries and get better performance.

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap would not help since the size of the under-page changes as the user drags her mouse or finger. You can't render constantly - and, besides, what would you render without the clips?

Comment: No, I'd render the original and target views of the transition and then manipulate the transform of the `ImageBrush`.

Comment: Hello Filip, Can I have example of page turn animation!!! I tried with your example but not getting success yet!!!

Comment: I never got to finish the control, but if you have a specific problem with the prototype above - I'd ask a separate question and add more details for what's not working for you.

Comment: Hello flip, thanks for reply, I have integrate your code in windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 RT. It's working well for right to left as per your example but for left to right, it's not working as page curl works. I have reference of pageturn.js. I need to create same thing in windows RT and windows phone 8.1.  Can you help me out??

Comment: Can you please guide me here, regarding point animation and rectangle transform, how they are working together for book turn animation ? I have checked example in silverlight where they are using path geometry and clip it in grid.

Comment: There is no point animation or path geometry clips. You can only use a `RectangleGeometry` and animate its `Transform`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it needs to be said that for the "Path with ImageBrush Fill" technique it is basically impossible to get the image to align exactly as you want using transforms, because the exact position of the image (of the imagebrush) inside the path clip depends on the extents of the path including Stroke.

So for example if you have a Bezier Path, you would need to calculate the actual extents of that Bezier to be then able to determine the exact scale/translate transform to apply to the image.

Stroke seems innocent, but when you have sharp angles in your poly-line path, the stroke makes a sharp pointy triangle! But also only to an extent, since after the angle gets really sharp, the triangle is not so pointy anymore! So, you would need to replicate the exact algorithm that does the Stroke for a Path.

Finally, I do need to admit there is the option to duplicate your Path for the Stroke, so have one with ImageBrush Fill and the other one without but with Stroke.