# How to animate book page turn effect in WebBrowser control in windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, page-flipping, ebook-reader

I am working on windows phone 8 book reader application, i am showing my all html pages on a web browser control, so now when i page change by click next button it suddenly change the page and navigate to another page. I want page should flip like a real book page. If anything required for the answer please let me know, but help me in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905589/path-geometry-clipping-equvalent-in-winrt/23028091#23028091

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a browser control the behavior is gonna be exactly as the website and you can't change it. but you can get a flip affect by using native windows8 xaml. Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507644.aspx

Comment: I try it and let you know, but it seems very complex, i have single page view only not two page view in my app.

Comment: but you are just loading the website and how you expect different behavior when it loads on your app.
The behavior is gonna be exactly as you load the website in normal browser.

Comment: It is not website, i have some static web pages having .html extension stored in isolatedStorage. Those pages i am loading.